# Fetching Integer List from Json

Tags: java, android, json

```
{
  "ID": 1,
  "Name": "Aman",
  "Description": "Food",
  "FeedbackTypeID": 2,
  "BanckMark": 50,
  "CutoffPercentage": 50,
  "IsOverridable": false,

  "ApplicableBranchId": [
    13,
    14
  ]
}
```

How to fetch `ApplicableBranchId` from `JSON`.

Comment: What you have tried yet???

Answer (score 1):

I create demo for get your `JSONArray` data.

You have to do like below to get data from `JSONArray`.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("ApplicableBranchId");
for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
        int data = jsonArray.getInt(i);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the `ApplicationBranchId` array out of the JSON object by using `.getJSONArray()` to return a `JSONArray` object. From here you can parse it how you like

```
JSONArray jsonArr = mainJSON.getJSONArray("ApplicableBranchId");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to get ApplicationBranchId from json

```
    JsonObject object = new JsonObject("response");
    JsonArray array = object.getJSONArray("ApplicableBranchId"); 
    for(int i ; array<lenght(); i++){
    Log.e("", "Branch Id -: " + array.getInt(i););}
```

Here BranchId is print in logcat.

Happy To Help and Happy Coding.

Comment: Hey @Shane just one correction in your code. array data is not string, that is integer data.