# How to pull an Int array from JSONOBJECT? Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, int

Tell me, please, how can I read an array of integers from the item "compatibility"?

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "text": "Some text",
    "action": 1,
    "compatibility": [ 4, 5 ]
},
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: Did you search it before you asking?

Comment: Yes, I did, but no one had yet tried to read the ARRAY of integers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068852/how-to-cast-jsonarray-to-int-array

Comment: Pretty bold claim.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34698980/parse-jackson-json-array-of-integers-to-java-array-without-using-extra-classes

Comment: Thank you! It helped!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34065174/fetching-integer-list-from-json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    JsonObject value = Json.createObjectBuilder()
        .add("id", 3)
        .add("text", "Some text")
        .add("action", 1)
        .add("phoneNumber", 
                Json.createArrayBuilder()
                .add(4)
                .add(5)
                .add(6)
    ).build();
    JsonArray array =  value.get("phoneNumber").asJsonArray();
    array.forEach( a -> {
        System.out.println( "int " +  a );      
    } );
```

from here you can already operate the integers according to the need